# Add to Scaffold Appbar a click counter with multiple pages

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, appbar, scaffold

Hello I'm creating an app with multiple pages using Navigators and routes.
I would like to add to the Scaffold Appbar a counter that increment every time a finger clicks on a screen button (also if they are more then one button present in the page).
Also if I change the pages, this counter must increase.
Can you help me to understand the issue?
I'm learing so probably the structure could be a "beginner" version.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Randal Schwartz commented, we could take advantage of the `onGenerateRoute` property of the `MaterialApp` class:

```
runApp(MaterialApp(
        home: BuilderPage(LoginArguments(false)),
        onGenerateRoute: generateRoute
));
```

By defining a custom `generateRoute` function:

```
int counter = 0; // global variable outside of the classes

Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case 'home':
      counter++;
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeScreen());
    case 'login':
      counter++;
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginScreen());
    case 'register':
      counter++;
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => RegisterScreen());
  }
}
```

The `counter` could be then displayed by the `Widget`s by loading it in their state:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  int _counter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() => _counter = counter);
  }

  void _increaseCounter() {
     counter++;
     setState(() => _counter++);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(child: Text(_counter.toString())),
       body: SafeArea(
               child: Center(child: 
                  GestureDetector(
                     onTap: () { _increaseCounter(); }, 
                     child: Text('test'),
                 ),
              ),
           ),
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

NB: this solution is not optimal. Please make sure to consider more advanced state management architectures, like `BLoC`, to better manage the data syncronization between different `Widget`s in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably hook some logging into the PageRouteBuilder, because every route goes through there from a given page (of course, it'd have to be on every page too).